# Cannot insert the value NULL into hours column (UPDATE with CASE, SQL Server)

Tags: sql

I am trying to update columns in a table (Adding hours to the Hours Column and multiplying PPP column by 20% and 30%) But it is not letting me.

My code:

```
Update New_Activity
SET Hours =
    CASE 
        WHEN Type = 'Bike' then Hours + 3
        WHEN Type = 'Hike' then Hours + 2
    END, 
    PPP =
    CASE 
        WHEN Type = 'Bike' then ppp*1.3
        WHEN Type = 'Hike' then ppp*1.2
    END
```

ERROR im getting:
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Hours', table '**********.dbo.New_Activity'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

This is for a class and our professor has made the Hours column
Not Null, so I unfortunately can't change that,
so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here,
as the Hours column is set to tiny int and I'm adding 2 / 3 hours to it. Please Advise!

Comment: Add `WHERE Type IN ('Bike', 'Hike')` at the end.

Comment: Thank you! Is a WHERE statement required for SET statements? Looking at earlier notes, we used where with set, but for this certain module with case statements, she did not include the where statement with set, so I was confused.

Comment: The WHERE clause is optional, but used here to avoid updating Train/Sail etc rows. (Your case expressions return NULL for those.)

Comment: You could also add `ELSE ppp` to the case _expressions_, to avoid NULL attempts. (But a WHERE clause is better, to keep transaction size down etc.)